# Docker Ubuntu PATH won't save

Tags: docker, path, ubuntu-20.04

I am using a Ubuntu image (Ubuntu 20.04). Essentially, I am trying to modify my PATH permanently so that every time I start the container I don't have to manually edit the PATH to find the new items I have installed. However, no matter what I do I am unable to make the change permanent. I have sunk some considerable time into the image, so I would very much like to find a solution so I don't have to rebuild the whole thing.

Here is the shell information

```
#ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    9 pts/1    00:00:00 sh 

# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

# PATH=$PATH:/kraken
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/kraken

#. ~/.profile
```

Now when I restart the container:

```
#echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Basically, the PATH was not saved. I have been through so many blogs and stack and I can't find anything that sticks. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can't you create your own image based on ubuntu, but with the expected path ? If I understood correctly, you changed the path inside the container and you want to persist this state. I think that it would be easier to start the container with the correct path.

Comment: @Fabien Thanks for the response. I don't believe this would work though. The kraken directory is not part of the original image. its the path where I installed the new software, so I can't create the PATH without creating the directory first

Comment: Then you need to create the directory in the image definition (in the DockerFile). You'll find a lot of resources on internet that will explain how to write a DockerFile. But the idea is that once your container is running, everything should be in the desired state. This is how you'll be able to launch several containers in parallel, all of them with the desired state.

Comment: @Fabien is it possible to edit the docker file with an already built image. It seems kind of silly that you simply can't add a PATH variable permanently.

Comment: The idea is that a container is ephemeral. You could have several containers, based on the same image, running at the same time. Imagine that you define different path values in each of them, then you start another container, which path value will be the one to use?  You can base your DockerFile on an existing image, like the one with Ubuntu and add the command to create the kraken directory (mkdir), copy what's needed inside this directory and then add it to your path with the env command. But if your question was to generate a DockerFile from a running container, I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that a container starts with a predefined path, you have to write a DockerFile to describe your expectations.
You could try with a DockerFile that looks like this :

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
COPY kraken /kraken #If you have some content to put in the kraken dir on your Docker instance, use mkdir -p /kraken otherwise
ENV PATH="/kraken:${PATH}"
```

Changing the path directly in the container at the runtime is not a solution if you want to keep the value for future containers. Docker containers are designed to be ephemeral and scalable.